# What is the better way to do synchronous loops on Nightwatch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightwatch.js

I am using `async/await` on `forEach`, but in some cases, when there is an issue inside loop, Nightwatch shows the error in the next scenario/step (there is something that is running as asynchronous and I need it step by step).

Comment: forEach and async don't mix up well together, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/823732

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nightwatch use the function perform() to make asynchonous commands  synchronous

```
browser.perform(done=> {
   Promise.all(#####ALL_YOUR_PROMISES_TO_RESOLVE#####).then(done).catch(done);
})
```

or you could also do something like

```
    myArray.forEach(one => {
       browser.perform(done=> {
          STUFFS_TO_DO;
          done();
       })
    })
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try with `Promises`